# Looking for something like Guava Cache with NavigableMap

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I'm looking for a Cache facility that can remove old entries if predefined interval expires (Like Guava Cache) but internally uses a NavigableMap interface.

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is something like that but you could use a [`ConcurrentSkipListMap<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) directly as a cache (see [NavigableMap & time-based caches](http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2012/03/navigablemap-timebased-caches.html) for an example) or keep a `NavigableMap<K,V>` in sync with a Guava Cache by loading/putting to both the cache and the navigable map and using a [`RemovalListener<K,V>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/RemovalListener.html) to remove entries from the navigable map when they are removed from the cache (see [Removal Listeners](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#removal-listeners)).

Comment: Thank you - I will look into it.